# How can I call a function from a different class in Swift?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I'm currently learning how to program a Cocoa MacOS app using Swift. I was wondering how you would access a function from a different class.

I currently have a class called `Button` (NSButton) and another class called `Window` (NSImageView). In `Window`, I have a function called `animate()`. I want `Window`'s `animate()` function to be carried out when `Button`'s `MouseDown` function is triggered.

This is what I tried:

```
    override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        Window.animate()
    }
```

How do I do this? I'm new to Swift, so thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume the `animate()` method is an instance method. So you need at least an instance of your `Window` to call that method.

Comment: I suggest reading some basic material about object-oriented programming.  Basically, the answer is that you get a reference to an object of that class type and call the function using that.

Comment: You can't call function directly on the class itself, You need to initalize your object and then call the function on this object's instance: `var window = Window()` and `window.animate()`

Comment: @Bogy You can if the function/method is a class or a static method.

Comment: An NSButton subclass accessing an NSWindow subclass?  That's something that I have never heard of.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay, thanks for trying to help. I found out what IBOutlets and IBActions were. They were the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If your button is in the window, you can use Swift's target and action mechanisms to call `animate()` without needing to access your window from another class:

```
button.target = self
button.action = #selector(animate)
```

with your animate function declared as

```
@objc func animate() {
    //...
}
```

If your button is in another window/view, you can use this method or the one you tried (overriding `mouseDown`); however, either way, `animate()` either must be a class func or you must have a reference of your window available to the button. For example, you could pass the window as an argument to initialize the button, or create a `static` instance of the window and access that instance.

Answer (score 0):

You want to access a function from a different class?

Simply declare the function as static function !

```
class window: UIViewController{

  static func animate()
  {
    ///
  }

}
```

and then you can call it anywhere in the program as

```
window.animate()
```